# Error uploading xls Codeigniter

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter

the error only occurs on a particular file. a lot of files with the extension XLS and XLSX have been uploaded.

My mimes:

```
'xlsx'  =>  array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'application/zip'),

'xls'   =>  array('application/excel', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/octet-stream','application/msexcel'),
```

Upload config:

```
  $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
  $config['max_size']   = '0';
```

The Error:

> The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Try Providing the Upload config specifically

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'xls|xlsx';
$config['max_size']   = '0';
```